# Read AVRO file using Python

Tags: java, python, mapreduce, avro

I have an AVRO file(created by JAVA) and seems like it is some kind of zipped file for hadoop/mapreduce, i want to 'unzip' (deserialize) it to a flat file. Per record per row.

I learned that there is an [AVRO package](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html) for python, and I installed it correctly. And run the example to read the AVRO file. However, it came up with the errors below and I am wondering what is going on reading the simplest example? Can anyone help me interpret the errors bellow.

```
>>> reader = DataFileReader(open("/tmp/Stock_20130812104524.avro", "r"), DatumReader())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/.../python2.7/site-packages/avro/datafile.py", line 240, in __init__
    raise DataFileException('Unknown codec: %s.' % self.codec)
avro.datafile.DataFileException: Unknown codec: snappy.
```

btw, if I do 'head' of file, and using VI to open up the first few lines of the AVRO file, I could see the schema definition together with some crappy weird characters - probably the zipped content. 
The starting bit of the raw AVRO file looks like below:

```
bj^A^D^Tavro.codec^Lsnappy^Vavro.schemaØ${"type":"record","name":"Stoc...
```

I don't know if those schemas would be necessary to read the AVRO file, something like below:

```
schema = avro.schema.parse(open("schema").read())
# include schema to do sth...
reader = DataFileReader(open("Stock_20130812104524.avro", "r"), DatumReader())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym, Java and Avro are not acronyms

Comment: @Steve Kuo You can create AVRO files using all kinds of languages like create CSV file using JAVA/Python/EXCEL.. right? I am not saying AVRO file is JAVA only just to give the reader more information about where the file come from .. don't know would that be helpful or misleading

Comment: I was just pointing out that Java and Avro are words, and not acronyms, and thus should not be written in all uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if there is no Xcode command line tools installed you cannot get snappy working. You can check by typing gcc at the command prompt to see if it is installed or not. If not then type `xcode-select –-install` to install it. Then installing python-snappy should work. Thanks Bin!

Answer (score 6):

Try `pip install python-snappy` - make sure you have installed [snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/) first.

Comment: I tried that with no luck. It was complaining about snappy-c.h missing... etc. which lead to a fail. Do I have to put the google snappy c library in the environment path first or etc... to make the python install work? I feel snappy might be the solution :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, you must install the snappy C library I linked to first.  It's here: https://code.google.com/p/snappy/ - or probably already packaged for your Linux distribution / Mac OS homebrew.

Comment: For Ubuntu, see [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and `apt-get install python-snappy libsnappy1 libsnappy-dev`

Comment: @B.Mr.W. Did you get it to work - or is the `.avro` file public?

Comment: I am working on the company environment and nested dependencies could not be that easily installed. I ended up using JAVA in that case which is one liner.

Answer (score -1):

wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/avro/avro-1.7.5/java/avro-tools-1.7.5.jar

java -jar avro/avro-tools-1.7.5.jar tojson input.avro > input

[More information refers here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/)