# Exception while reading avro file in python

Tags: python, file, avro

I am new to Python,
Im trying to read avro file in python using the below code.

```
reader = DataFileReader(open(avro_records, "rb"), DatumReader())
```

but it is throwing the exception as below Unknown codec snappy. Do I need to specify snappy?

```
raise DataFileException('Unknown codec: %s.' % self.codec)
avro.datafile.DataFileException: Unknown codec: snappy.
```

can you help me how to resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read AVRO file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453026/read-avro-file-using-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue in using snappy with avro in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699490/issue-in-using-snappy-with-avro-in-python)